# SwiftMail : How customize my message body

Tags: php

I want to customise my message in SwiftMail. I'te try to send an link as email body content but it not going.

Code

```html
<?php

 $message_body = '<a href="www.lien_test.com/Admin/Confirm_account?code="'.$mail_verification_code.'" ">Verifier votre Email</a>';


  $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.googlemail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
  ->setUsername('myemailis......')
  ->setPassword('*******')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Test Application Ecole'))
  ->setFrom(['codex@gmail.com' => 'JP-Evenemential'])
  ->setTo([$_POST['prof_email']])
  ->setBody('Votre Inscription a été prise en compte. Cliquez sur le lien ci dessous pour confirmer votre compte.
    '.$message_body.'
    ')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);


?>
```

Email Send is ok, but i dont receved Confirm Account as a link.
This is my result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2kwn.png)

Can someone help me ?
Sorry am a french guy.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

you can use

```
->addPart('<q>un message HTML</q>', 'text/html')
```

or

```
->setBody('<q>un message HTML</q>', 'text/html');
```

to had your html text.